# How to recover website converted to sln

Tags: html, asp.net, database, visual-web-developer-2010, sln-file

I work on visual web developer 2010, and by mistake one of the pc's @ school converted my project to sln or something.

Now it seems like it cleared my `App_Data` folder - means my database is gone.

Anyone knows how can I fix it? or how can I convert it back?

Comment: Visual Studio probably converted it from a "Web Site" to a "Web Application". If so, technically your `App_Data` folder should still be on disk but perhaps no longer is included in your project. Can you confirm it's existance on disk?